# Как записать/прочитать данные на SD card (карту памяти) micropython esp8266

Tags: esp8266, micropython

Всем привет.

У меня есть [esp8266mod nodemcu.](https://i2.wp.com/randomnerdtutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/ESP8266-NodeMCU-kit-12-E-pinout-gpio-pin.png?ssl=1) С прошивкой Micropython esp8266-20191220-v1.12.

Я хочу сохранять данные с датчика на SDкарту (это ж проще всего, подумал я).

Поползав по интернету, я нашел видео [MicroPython Hardware: SD Card Storage with Tony D! @micropython](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1nzG1BdPps)
в котором Тони Работает с SD картой именно на ESP8266. Однако у меня нет красивого адаптера. Что делать? Возьми паяльник и сделай некрасивый, ответил мне гугл. Припаяв провода к SDcard-microSDcard адаптеру я столкнулся с вопросом. На какие пины подключать карту. Вспомнив добрым словом китайцев (и не найдя толком информации) Я решил что подключу на "правую сторону" D5 D6 D7.

Дальше я [скачал sdcard.py](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/drivers/sdcard/sdcard.py) Загрузил его на ESP. И запустил код из примера

```
#Example usage on ESP8266:
import machine, sdcard, os
sd = sdcard.SDCard(machine.SPI(1), machine.Pin(15))
os.mount(sd, '/sd')
os.listdir('/')
```

на что репл ответил мне

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 19] ENODEV
```

Буду делать как Тони, подумал я и... путём, прямо таки, научного тыка я нашел вариант, который не выдает ошибку.

```
import machine, sdcard, os
sd = sdcard.SDCard(machine.SPI(1), machine.Pin(15))
os.umount('/')
vfs = os.VfsFat(sd)
```

Ура, подумал я и радостно ввел os.listdir().

```
>>> os.listdir()
[]
```

Ответил мне Mu. Думаю ESPlorer ответил бы также.
Приступимс. Радости моей не было предела...

```
>>> f = open('text.txt', 'w')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 1] EPERM
>>>
```

Полагаю, что я где-то что-то прослушал или упустил. В основном потому что мой английский не так хорош, как хотелось бы. Прочитав руководство с сайта Адафрут, я дошел до той же точки и того же результата. Карта (Toshiba m203 16Gb) отформатирована в FAT32.

Да. Пробовал закинуть текстовый файл на карту, listdir его тоже не видит.

Может где-то есть инструкции или примеры кода, желательно и с чтением и с записью.

Comment: Я пару лет назад пытался сделать примерно то же самое, безуспешно. Сейчас попробовал: в первом варианте sd как бы успешно монтируется в папку `/sd`, но при попытке сделать listlir этой папки кидает ошибку `[Errno 5] EIO`. Во втором варианте аналогично кидает ошибку `[Errno 1] EPERM`. Пробовал еще вариант демонтировать корень (`os.umount('/')`), примонтировать вместо него sd (`os.mount(sd, '/sd')`) - `listdir` как и в первом варианте кидает `EIO`. В общем, тоже безуспешно.