# Как грамотно сохранять данные? micropython esp8266 и/или esp32 (data logging )

Tags: esp8266, micropython

Всем привет.
Вопрос абсолютно концептуальный.
И по сути - что почитать/посмотреть?

У нас есть плата  ESP8266nodemcu и/или ESP-wroom-32. Есть micropython. Подключаем к ней сколько-то датчиков. она их с какой-то периодичностью опрашивает. И как-то данные с этих датчиков нужно сохранить. Конечным результатом должна стать возможность посмотреть график измерений за n-ый период времени. 
Я для себя вижу три возможных варианта событий.

1. интернета нет вообще.
2. есть стабильное подключение к интернету.
3. периодически в зоне действия устройства появляется девайс-приёмопередатчик.

1) Этот вариант казался мне самым простым для освоения в роли новичка. Однако [записать все на карту у меня не получилось](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1120931/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-sd-card-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-micropython-esp8266)

2)Здесь есть чуть больше миллиона решений, однако. Подразумевается что мы не используем публичные сервисы вроде IFTTT или "народного мониторинга".
Первое, что мне пришло в голову - а не сохранить ли все в GoogleSheets. И я нашел [Weather station based on ESP32 and MicroPython](https://blog.gypsyengineer.com/en/diy-electronics/weather-station-based-on-esp32-and-micropython.html). Но мой Python оказался не так крут. Хотя потихоньку я подхожу к осознанию то что написано в этой статье. Ну и полагаю, что 8266 не потянет всю эту штуку. Для яндекс-диска мелькали библиотеки, yо они, вроде как, для простого питона.
Следующим в поиске стал MQTT протокол. Если использовать его для большой сети (как он и задуман), то проблем тоже нет: стационарный ПК, либо RaspberryPi с полноценным Pyton, Mosquitto и т.д. А если что-то лёгкое вроде теплицы. Щас куда ни плюнь в MQTT-брокера попадешь. 
С чем лучше работать именно с точки зрения записи данных в долгосрочное хранилище для ПК, для Android, и для iOS/MacOS.

3) и вот тут поле не пахано. У нас же на борту ещё и блюпуп есть. И куда копать ваще непонятно. Ну то есть, если я хочу от солнечной панельки/батарейки питать все свои датчики, то по идее блюпуп рулит. 
Но как это грамотно делается я вообще ничего не нашел. (понятно что плохо исткал)

3.1)А LoRa можно к ESP прикрутить? (да можно [ESP32 and ESP8266 point-to-point (ESP-Now): Fast and efficient. Comparison with LoRa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NsBN42B80Q))

Comment: API для google docs или yandex disc это просто набор http сервисов. Стандартный способ обращения к таким сервисам на обычном Python - библиотека requests. У micropython вместо этой библиотеки есть urequests, суть остается та же.

Comment: `Ну и полагаю, что 8266 не потянет всю эту штуку.` - должно потянуть, по идее, нужно пробовать. Единственное ограничение которое я тут вижу - объем встроенной памяти под скрипт.

Comment: 2 - тут я еще вижу простой вариант с собственным сервисом на базе pythonanywhere + flask. Устройство стучится на сервис, передает туда свои данные post-запросом, сервис заносит данные новой строкой в базу или в файл. Тут конечно вопрос с авторизацией - как сервис будет определять, что это наша теплица, а какой-то левый бот.

Comment: Добро. Пока буду двигаться в этом направлении